# Can we set custom permission of a list using features in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, custom-lists

I am working on SharePoint 2010 . Creating features to automate the custom list creation. I am assigned a task to automatically set the custom permission of each list using features programatically. I would like to know if it is possible and if yes how.

There are 2 things here:

1. Custom permission level is to be created with contribute-delete permissions.
2. This permission and default available permissions are to be set to lists which are custom made using features.

please do specify which methods to override if at all possible. Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the FeatureActivated method of your feature receiver with code similar to the following:

```cs
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;
        SPList list = web.GetList(web.Url + "/Lists/MyList");

        SPRoleDefinition roleDef = new SPRoleDefinition();
        roleDef.BasePermissions = SPBasePermissions.DeleteListItems 
            | SPBasePermissions.AddListItems 
            | SPBasePermissions.EditListItems;
        roleDef.Description = "Custom permissions deployed by feature";
        roleDef.Name = "Contribute-Delete";
        web.RoleDefinitions.Add(roleDef);
        roleDef = web.RoleDefinitions[roleDef.Name];
        SPMember owner = web.SiteUsers[@"Domain\username"];
        SPUser user = web.SiteUsers[@"Domain\username"];
        web.SiteGroups.Add("Contribute-Delete",owner, user,"A group for contribute delete access");
        SPGroup ContributeDeleteGroup = web.SiteGroups["Contribute-Delete"];
        SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(ContributeDeleteGroup);
        roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDef);
        list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
        list.RoleAssignments.Add(ContributeDeleteGroup);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable post it worked perfectly well i was successfully able to implement it.

Comment: hi could you please tell me if it is possible to assign an ootb permission to a list? if yes how. I dont think its a big question hence i'm asking this in comments section thanx in advance.

Comment: @Sreejit Yes you can, `SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(SPPrincipal); roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Contributor));` where `SPPrincipal` is the user or group you want to grant the permission to.